# Как узнать содержит ли Cursor что-либо?

Tags: android, sqlite

Делаю я запрос на получение строк из SQLite(Select) стандартным методом query().
Он возрващает класс Cursor. Но как узнать что этот результута запроса не пустой и что по нашему запросу что-то есть и Cursor что-то в себе содержит?

Comment: [Что делать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), когда кто то ответил на мой вопрос

Answer (score 4):

как получите `cursor`, вызовите у него `cursor.getCount()`. Если результат не 0, то значит записи есть

Comment: Спасибо. Не увидел у него такой метод.